# General String extension conversion using reified typing

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-reified-type-parameters

I started working with the reified keyword when attempting to implement a general String to numeric String extension method. The following compiles and runs, but I'd like to improve it before using it in production code:

```
inline fun <reified T> String.convertTo():T {
    return when(T::class.simpleName){
        Int::class.simpleName->{(this.toIntOrNull() ?: 0) as T}
        Float::class.simpleName->{(this.toFloatOrNull() ?: 0f) as T}
        Double::class.simpleName->{(this.toDoubleOrNull() ?: 0.0) as T}
        else -> throw IllegalArgumentException("Can't convert type $(T::class.simpleName)")
    }
}
```

I like the consise caller code for this:

```
val time:Int by lazy {((evaluateExpression("time").convertTo<Float>().times(1000f))).toInt()}
```

Two things I'd like to do if it's possible in this scenario:

1) I haven't been able to figure the correct syntax to constrain reified T to only the allowed types - I'd like to exhaust the when conditions and remove the else->throw

2) T::class.java doesn't compare correctly to the other types' class type (i.e. Int::class.java) so I've resorted to comparing simpleName strings - what would be better?

Is there a way to restrict the type and a better way to compare class types here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. You can only constrain `T` if you have a common supertype between the types you want to handle. Of course you can't add supertypes to the built-in `Int`, `Float`, etc. classes, but these are all `Number`s, which you could use:

   ```
   inline fun <reified T : Number> String.convertTo(): T
   ```

   However, so are `Byte`, `Long`, and `Short`, so you'd still have to handle those... But more importantly, `Number` is just an abstract class and not a sealed one (you could plausibly implement your own if you needed to), so the `when` expression has no way of being exhaustive in this case. So you'll just have to keep the `else` branch, unfortunately.
2. Good news for this part of the question, using just `::class` and comparing `KClass` instances should work (I've also removed some braces):

   ```
   inline fun <reified T : Number> String.convertTo(): T {
       return when (T::class) {
           Int::class -> (this.toIntOrNull() ?: 0) as T
           Float::class -> (this.toFloatOrNull() ?: 0f) as T
           Double::class -> (this.toDoubleOrNull() ?: 0.0) as T
           else -> throw IllegalArgumentException("Can't convert type $(T::class.simpleName)")
       }
   }
   ```

Comment: Many thanks - I'll put all of your suggestions into production.